# OpenVPN Port forwarding on a OpenVZ VPS

Tags: iptables, openvpn, port, openvz, forwarding

I've been trying for the past 3 hours to forward the 443 port from my client to the 20443 port on my server (CentOS 7 on OpenVZ), so i can access it on myserverip:20443.
I have OpenVPN Access installed and this is the client config on it : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xghCH.png

I use this script to forward.

$1 = Client port (here 443)

$2 = Outside port (here 20443)

172.28.224.30 = Private client (fixed ip)

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -A FORWARD -i venet0-p tcp --dport $2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i venet0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport $2 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.28.224.30:$1
iptables -A FORWARD -i as0t0 -p tcp --dport $1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i as0t0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport $1 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.28.224.30:$1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d EXTERNAL_IP --dport $2 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.28.224.30:$1
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.28.224.30 --dport $1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i venet0 -d 172.28.224.30 --dport $2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d EXTERNAL_IP --dport $2 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.28.224.30:$1
```

And when I do on SSH "curl 172.28.224.30:443" I have the result.

When I try access to it, i get a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, (not a CONNECTION_REFUSED). So I think the port 20443 is accepted, but doesn't redirect to 172.28.224.30:443 :/

Here's my ifconfig :

```
as0t0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.224.1  netmask 255.255.248.0  destination 172.27.224.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.232.1  netmask 255.255.248.0  destination 172.27.232.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 12  bytes 1075 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 981 (981.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 16436
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 82  bytes 6832 (6.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 82  bytes 6832 (6.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

venet0: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0  destination 127.0.0.1
        inet6 2001:41d0:51:1::825  prefixlen 56  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 2900  bytes 206056 (201.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2637  bytes 364050 (355.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

venet0:0: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet EXTERNAL_IP  netmask 255.255.224.0  broadcast EXTERNAL_BROADCAST destination EXTERNAL_IP
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
```

Is there something I did wrong ?

I also tried to do : socat TCP4-LISTEN:20443,fork TCP4:172.28.224.30:443
No success :(

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate but I can't find it right now. You need to check with your hosting provider if they allow this - many don't.

Comment: Did you receive any errors from your iptables script?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses ! I don't think my provider block it (VPS from OVH) because I saw my /etc/sysconfig/iptables and their is a lot of OpenVPN entries (and OpenVPN work perfectly). I have no error on my iptables script :/

Comment: BTW here's my iptables -L : http://pastebin.com/TkE61sqP